# Replacing in a sample after x number of samples have been taken in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a simulation where after every 10 draws, everything drawn will be replaced.
However, it is running for 100 samples. I am trying to have all 100 draws done at once, under different seeds, but I am trying to regulate the seeds. I do not know how to have the replace occur every 10 draws, though. Here is some code:

```
i = 0

while 1=1 :{
    x <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = FALSE) # HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE REPLACE TO BE TRUE EVERY 10
    # my thought is to put an if statement of some sort that resets the sample, but I am not sure how 
    # to accomplish such
    if(x >= 1000):
        print("Seed ", i, " exceeded expectations")
    i = i+1
}
```

I realize the above code does not have a break, this is just some starter code for as far as I have figured out. Any insight is appreciated

Comment: No, I am trying to have all 100 draws be under the same seed. Doing what you have would change the seed each 10, but all 100 need to be under the same seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you are thinking of?

```
lapply(1:100,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  sample(1:100,10,replace = F)
})
```